# Snort Rule to prevent malicious file from downloading

Tags: snort

I am looking for a snort rule that prevents malicious file from downloading. If there isn't exist any rule then how to create custom rule. Like give the signature of file to prevent from future download.

Comment: **alert http any any -> any any (msg: "Malicious file detected"; sid:5; filemd5:Path-to-file-where-hashes-stored; classtype:policy-violation; rev:1;)**

Comment: This is suricata rule. And also you'll have to make some changes to suricata.yaml file.